# How to match a list of strings in two different files using a loop structure?

Tags: unix, file-io, awk

I have a file processing task that I need a hand in. I have two files (matched_sequences.list and multiple_hits.list).

INPUT FILE 1 (matched_sequences.list):

```
>P001 ID
 ABCD .... (very long string of characters)

>P002 ID
 ABCD .... (very long string of characters)

>P003 ID
ABCD ... ( " " " " )
```

INPUT FILE 2 (multiple_hits.list):

```
ID1
ID2
ID3
....
```

What I want to do is match the second column (ID2, ID4, etc.) with a list of IDs stored in multiple_hits.list. Then create a new matched_sequences file similar to the original but which excludes all IDs found in multiple_hits.list (about 60 out of 1000). So far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
X=$(cat matched_sequences.list | awk '{print $2}')
Y=$(cat multiple_hits.list | awk '{print $1}')

while read matched_sequenes.list
do
[ $X -ne $Y ] && (cat matched_sequences.list | awk '{print $1" "$2}') > new_matched_sequences.list
done
```

I get the following error raised:
-bash: read: `matched_sequences.list': not a valid identifier
Many thanks in advance!

EXPECTED OUTPUT (new_matched_sequences.list):

Same as INPUT FILE 1 with all IDs in multiple_hits.list excluded

Comment: Your input files seem not clear enough. It would be helpful adding some more lines and separating them as two sections. It would also be helpful adding expected output.

Comment: You are missing a right parentheses at the end of the line in the while loop

Comment: @mikebolt: Yes, thanks for noticing! I edited it and the code still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter **awk** answer is possible, with a tiny script reading first the file with the IDs to exclude, and then the file containing the sequences. The script would be as follows (comments make it long, it's just three useful lines in fact:

```
BEGIN { grab_flag = 0 }
# grab_flag will be used when we are reading the sequences file
# (not absolutely necessary to set here, though, because we expect the file will start with '>')

FNR == NR { hits[$1] = 1 ; next } # command executed for all lines of the first file: record IDs stored in multiple_hits.list
# otherwise we are reading the second file, containing the sequences:
/^>/ { if (hits[$2] == 1) grab_flag = 0 ; else grab_flag = 1 } # sets the flag indicating whether we have to output the sequence or not
grab_flag == 1 { print }
```

And if you call this script `exclude.awk`, you will invoke it this way:

```
awk -f exclude.awk multiple_hits.list matched_sequences.list
```

Comment: Many thanks for that! When you say the BEGIN line is not completely necessary, is there another way to set the flags which are used as conditions?

Comment: Yes, you can use `-v grab_flag=0` on your awk commandline. But if your fasta file is correctly formatted, the first line should start with a `>` character, so the line of my script starting with `\^>\` would do the job at that moment, which is fine and would allow the script to run flawlessly. (BTW, please upvote if you found my solution useful! ;))

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function chomp(s) {
    sub(/^[ \t]*/, "", s)
    sub(/[ \t\r]*$/, "", s)
    return s
}
BEGIN {
    file = ARGV[--ARGC]
    while ((getline line < file) > 0) {
        a[chomp(line)]++
    }
    RS = ""
    FS = "\n"
    ORS = "\n\n"
}
{
    id = chomp($1)
    sub(/^.* /, "", id)
}
!(id in a)
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk matched_sequences.list multiple_hits.list > new_matched_sequences.list
```